# Профессиональное развитие разработчика

Tags: разработка-игр

Занимаюсь не очень интересной работой, за которую нормально платят. Пишу на джаве и C++. Задачи однотипные (энтерпрайз) и я задумываюсь о том, как мне дальше развиваться, чтобы не сидеть в зоне комфорта, быть ценным специалистом и заниматься интересными вещами.

Что я могу изучать понемногу каждый день, чтобы найти себе интересные проекты в какой-нибудь компании? Скорее всего, мне был бы интересен геймдев, но советы начинать с написания своего графического и физического движка меня пугают. Надоело писать велосипеды.

Есть предложения?

Comment: Вопрос философский. Чем вы хотите заниматься. Какие игры вам нравятся? Соответствует ли уровень тех игр которые вам нравятся тому которыми вы сейчас занимаетесь, или вы хотите создавать игры посерьезнее?

Comment: @nick_n_a, я хочу разрабатывать игры, но занимаюсь на своей работе энтерпрайзом. Датабазы, спринг, рест, soap и т.д. Надоело.

Comment: Игра состоит в зависимости от сложности, из нескольких частей. Кроме движка есть ещё геометрия, статистика, графы, (возможно искуственный интелект) или какие-то ещё сложные вещи. Возможно тут есть разработчики игр, и больше скажут. На собеседовании на геймдев меня спрашивали графы и что-то по математике.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а есть какая-то литература, чтобы можно было изучать выбранную область? На разработку игр уровня WoW я не претендую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Игровые компании

Всё сильно зависит от роли в игровой компании. Если мы говорим о программировании, то я могу выделить несколько ролей

### Разработчик игровой логики

Движки, редакторы, основы графики, особенности платформы, парадигмы и подходы, искусственный интеллект.

### Разработчик движка

Графика, платформа, инструментарий для разработчиков игровой логики, сеть, социальные сети, работа с памятью, системы менджемнта памяти, алгоритмы, физические движки.

### Разработчик сопутствующих систем

Билд система, инструменты и редакторы, скрипты, конверторы.

---

По моему опыту разработчика движков и мобильных и кроссплатформенных игр, джентльменский набор разработчика игровых движков включает в себя:

- Графика - как работает openGL/directX/Metal/Vulkan, шейдеры, текстуры, буферы, бачинг, конвеер графической системы, типичные подходы, используемые для систем рендеринга, материалы, форматы изображений, форматы моделей, скининг.
- Знание особенностей платформ, с которыми собираешься работать.
- Знание типичных шаблонов (Finite State Machine, Entity Component System, Listener, Observer, Singleton) и ООП. (Функциональное программирование пока что не ворвалось в мир энетрпрайз игр)
- Скриптовые языки и их рантайм. Многие игровые движки написаны на С++, у которого довольно раздутый синтаксис, не очень дружелюбный менеджмент памяти и нет рефлексии кода. Это основные причины, по которым игровую логику непосредственно предпочитают писать как скрипт, который движок может запустить в безопасном режиме. Программисты игровой логики очень редко задаются вопросом, нужен ли в каком-то конкретном случае конструктор копирования или конструктор перемещения. Это работа программистов движка - убедиться, что пользователи их движка не смогут ничего сломать или неправильно использовать.
- Знание существующих игровых движков. Unreal Engine, например, бесплатный с открытым кодом и очень хорошо написан.

Некоторые любят начать с теории. Для них я могу порекомендовать "Game Engine Architecture" и "OpenGL Programming Guide" (не знаю, есть ли перевод на русский).

Для тех же, кто любит сначала делать, а потом разбираться с последствиями, могу посоветовать сделать свою игру на популярных игровых движках (Unity - беспроигрышный вариант). Здесь **очень** поможет участие в гейм джемах. Ну а для полного понимания работы движков, как бы банально это ни звучало, нужно написать свой (чисто в образовательных целях!).